# How well can we predict asteroid impact location?

Tags: trajectory, asteroid, observation

> concern in December 2004 when initial observations indicated a probability up to 2.7% that it would hit Earth on April 13, 2029

<sub>- wikipedia on 99942 Apophis</sub>

So we can predict that something might hit us 25 years in the future. Let us assume for the sake of argument we cannot influence it while in space. What would be the timeline and accuracy of coordinates to evacuate humans and valuable equipment?

Comment: For a precise prediction of an asteroid impact location we need very precise orbit data of the asteroid. For this data we need many precise position measurements over a sufficiently long time interval. For 25 years in the future we should have observations for a much longer time than 25 months.

Comment: @Uwe perhaps the question is better suited to worldbuilding.SE? Though considering NASA's precautions about the Moon return crew I would assume a scenario with a supermassive hydrogen bomb hitting a random spot on the planet with 2.7% probability be accounted for under numerous protocols.

Comment: Depends on the trajectory.  Predictions for something nearly co-orbital (like 99942 Apophis) are far less sensitive to errors than predictions for something on a hyperbolic trajectory coming from interstellar space.  (For something on a hyperbolic trajectory, a one-second error in impact time means *at least* a 30-kilometer error in impact point.)